# $X$ is normal matrix and $AX=XB$ and $XA=BX$.why $A{X^*} = {X^*}B$ and ${X^*}A = B{X^*}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B,X \in {M_n}$ and $X$ is normal matrix and

> $AX=XB$
>
> $XA=BX$

Why $A{X^*} = {X^*}B$ and ${X^*}A = B{X^*}$?

Comment: Closely related: [Show that if $T_1, T_2$ are normal operators that commutes then $T_1+T_2$ and $T_1T_2$ are normal.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368576/show-that-if-t-1-t-2-are-normal-operators-that-commutes-then-t-1t-2-and)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Set
   $$
   X' = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 \\
   X & 0
   \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } A' = \begin{pmatrix}
   A & 0 \\
   0 & B
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   Then $X'$ is normal and commutes with $A'$. Thus you have reduced the problem to the statement that if $XA = AX$ then $X^{\ast}A = AX^{\ast}$.
2. Now use the fact that $X$ is diagonalizable, and now you are reduced to the case where $X$ is diagonal.
3. Prove it when $X$ is diagonal.

BTW, this is (a special case of) the Fuglede-Putnam theorem.