# Normal Operators: Meet

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Normal Operators:
$$\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{H}):=\{N:N^*N=NN^*\}$$

Borel Calculus:
$$\mathcal{B}(N):=\{\eta({N}):\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})\}$$

Commutativity:
$$N_\pm\in\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{H}):\quad N_+N_-=N_-N_+$$

Borel Calculus:
$$\mathcal{B}(N_+)\subseteq\mathcal{B}(N_-)\lor\mathcal{B}(N_-)\subseteq\mathcal{B}(N_+)$$

Meet Operator:
$$N_+\wedge N_-\in\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\mathcal{B}(N_\pm)\subseteq\mathcal{B}(N_+\wedge N_-)$$
*(Symbolic Meet!)*

Comment: Please avoid edits unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Yes! It was necessary this time, though. *(See edit-history.)*

Comment: In its current form, I cannot find a question in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Yeaaahh, I got it! :D*
*(Thanks to David C. Ullrich!)*

**Borel Calculus**

Given Hilbert Space $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Normal Operators:
$$N_+:=1\oplus0\quad N_-:=0\oplus1$$

Commutativity:
$$N_+N_-=0\oplus0=N_-N_+$$

Borel Calculus:
$$\mathcal{B}(N_+)\cap\mathcal{B}(N_-)=\{0\oplus0\}$$
Counterexample!

**Meet Operator**

Product Measure:
$$(E_+\wedge E_-)(A_+\times A_-):=E_+(A_+)E_-(A_-)$$

Borel Isomorphism:
$$\Phi:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\leftrightarrow\mathbb{C}:\quad\Phi\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$$

Meet Operator:
$$N_+\wedge N_-:=\Phi(E_+\wedge E_-)$$

Meet Calculus:*
$$\eta(N_+\wedge N_-)=(\eta\circ\Phi)(E_+\wedge E_-)$$
$$\vartheta(E_+\wedge E_-)=(\vartheta\circ\Phi^{-1})(N_+\wedge N_-)$$

Borel Calculus:
$$\mathcal{B}(N_\pm)\leq\mathcal{B}(E_+\wedge E_-)=\mathcal{B}(N_+\wedge N_-)$$

**See thread: [Pushforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365246/79762)*