# Matrix Algebras: Generator

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

**Problem**

Given the algebra $\mathcal{M}_\mathbb{C}(2)$.

Denote the normals:
$$\mathcal{N}:=\{N\in\mathcal{M}_\mathbb{C}(2):N^*N=NN^*\}$$

And their calculus:
$$\mathcal{N}(N):=\{\eta(N):\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\}$$

Regard commuting ones:
$$N,N'\in\mathcal{N}:\quad N'N=NN'$$

> Do they admit one:
>   $$N_0\in\mathcal{N}:\quad\mathcal{N}(N)\cup\mathcal{N}(N')\subseteq\mathcal{N}(N_0)$$

Are there counterexamples?

**Attempt**

Choose one nondiagonal:
$$N=U^*DU\quad N'=D'$$

There exists one with:
$$\eta_0(N)=\eta_0(U^*DU)\neq\eta_0(D)$$

But how to proceed then?

**Reference**

I need this for: [Superalgebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1350143/79762)

Comment: Maybe I misread your definitions but $N_+$ and $N_-$ both lie in  the subalgebra generated by $\mathrm{diag}(-1,1)$.

Comment: Actually I am fairly certain that it is impossible to construct two such matrices, since each $2 \times 2$-matrix is either scalar or generates its own centralizer.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck: I just noticed that $N'=1-N$ and $N=1-N'$. So it is $\mathcal{N}(N)=\mathcal{N}(N')$.

Comment: Yep, and this will always happen as stated in my second comment

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck: Yes right. Let me try another one. *(Modifying my thread.)*

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck: Hmm it must be nondiagonal??

Comment: Hm, I would guess that $\mathrm{diag}(1,2,3,4)$ will generate a subalgebra containing your two matrices. The generated subalgebra has dimension $4$ (look at the minimal polynomial) and is hence the algebra of diagonal matrices containing your two chosen ones.

Comment: Additionally you actually cannot choose them nondiagonal since two commuting normal matrices can be brought into diagonal form simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should never be possible:

Let $N_1,N_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be two commuting normal matrices. Then (by the spectral theorem and the fact that they commute) there is a unitary matrix $P$ such that $PN_1P^*=D_1,PN_2P^*=D_2$ are diagonal.

Take now any diagonal matrix $D$ with pairwise distinct diagonal entries. Then $D$ generates an algebra of dimension $n$ (look at its minimal polynomial) and each element of this algebra is diagonal, so $D$ generates the subalgebra of diagonal matrices. In particular $D_1$ and $D_2$ lie in it and $N_1,N_2$ hence lie in the subalgebra generated by $P^*DP$.

Comment: How do you know that they are diagonalized by the same matrix?

Comment: Because they commute. Any set of commuting matrices each of which is diagonalizable itself can be brought into diagonal form simultaneously.
See (e.g.) here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/simultaneous-diagonalization

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the link.