# Normal Operators: "Zorn"

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Normal Operators:
$$\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{H}):=\{N:N^*N=NN^*\}$$
*(Possibly unbounded!)*

Borel Calculus:
$$\mathcal{B}(N):=\{\eta(N):\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})\}$$
*(Normal Operator!)*

Commuting System:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})\subseteq\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{H}):\quad[\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}),\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})]=0$$
*(Spectral Measures!)*

> Maximal Operator:
>   $$N_\infty\in\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})\subseteq\mathcal{B}(N_\infty)$$
>   *(Existence & Uniqueness?)*

**Motivation**

In application one deals with commuting normal operators.

Reduction from *two* operators: [Meet](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1350143/79762)
Consider commuting normal operators $N$ and $N'$.
As they commute they admit a product spectral measure $E\wedge E'$.
But the situation is even better: They admit a wedge normal operator $N\wedge N'$.
That is its Borel calculus contains both original operators $N$ and $N'$.

Thus one may reduce the case of finitely many commuting normal operators
to the study of only *one* normal operator and its Borel calculus.

For arbitrarily many the question was still open here...

Comment: @Norbert: I added a motivation. *(See edit!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it.. :D*

Hilbert Space:
$$\Omega:=\mathcal{P}^2(\mathbb{C}):\quad\mathcal{H}:=\ell^2(\Omega)$$

Normal Operators:
$$N_\omega:\mathcal{D}N_\omega\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N_\omega\varphi:=1_\omega\varphi$$

Commuting System:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):=\{N_\omega:\omega\in\Omega\}$$

Borel Calculus:
$$\#\mathcal{B}(N_\infty)\leq\#\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})\leq\#\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})\\
<\#\mathcal{P}^2(\mathbb{C})=\#\Omega=\#\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$$
*(Contradiction!)*