# Euclidean Spaces: Embedding

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Given the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Are there maps:
$$\eta\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}),\vartheta\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2):\quad \vartheta\circ\eta=1_{\mathbb{R}^2}$$

What about measurables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there were such continuous maps. Then $\eta$ would be injective. Hence it's restriction to the closed unit disc is a homeomorphism. The image of that disc would be a closed bounded interval. But the disc is not homeomorphic to an interval: removing an interior point from the interval leaves a disconnected set, while removing any point from the disc leaves a connected set.

---

Added later: Let me take a crack at the measurable case too. ("Measurable" will mean "Borel measurable".) Recall that each $x\in (0,1)$ has a unique decimal expansion $x = .x_1 x_2\dots $ that doesn't end in a string of $9$'s; all decimal expansions mentioned will be of this sort. We want to define a map $f: (0,1)\times (0,1) \to (0,1)$ as follows:

$$f((.x_1 x_2\dots , .y_1 y_2\dots)) = .x_1 y_1 x_2 y_2 \dots.$$

Then $f$ is injective, which is nice, but there are a few problems with $f$: i) Why is $f$ measurable? ii) $f$ isn't onto (for example, $.0909\overline {09}$ is not in the range). To settle i) consider the function $d_n:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $d_n(.x_1 x_2\dots) = x_n.$ Then $d_n$ is measurable on $(0,1).$ (I'm going to leave this to you for now; it's a kind of fun little exercise). Since $f(x,y) = \sum d_n(x)/10^{2n-1} +\sum d_n(y)/10^{2n},$ $f$ is measurable.

To take care of ii), let $E_n = \{x\in (0,1): d_k(x) = 9, k = n,n+2,n+4, \dots \}.$ Then each $E_n$ is measurable, hence so is $E= \cup E_n.$ You can check that $f$ is a bijection between $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ and $(0,1)\setminus E.$ Furthermore, $f^{-1}$ is measurable, since

$$f^{-1}(x)=(\sum d_{2n-1}(x)/10^{n},\sum d_{2n}(x)/10^{n}).$$

So now let $g$ be a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb {R}^2$ onto $(0,1)\times (0,1).$ Also define $h: \mathbb {R}\to [(0,1)\setminus E]$ in the obvious way: $h(x) =x,x\in (0,1)\setminus E, h=0$ elsewhere; clearly $h$ is measurable. Then we can take $\eta = f\circ g,$  $\vartheta = g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ h.$ Recalling that compositions of Borel measurable functions are Borel measurable, we see $\eta, \vartheta$ do the job.

Comment: Nice argumentation!!! *(Compactness & Connectedness?)* (+1)!!!

Comment: Which of course is the "simpler" argument I alluded to... You know we're both going to be famous, heh-heh

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Na not famous just a nice result. ^^

Answer (score 4):

A continuous map from $\Bbb  R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ cannot be injective. This is trivial; proof below. It's higher-dimensional versions, like the fact that a continuous map from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$ cannot be injective, that I suspect are non-trivial.

Given two points $a,b\in\Bbb R^2$, let $[a,b]$ denote the line segment from $a$ to $b$. Say $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is continuous. Suppose $f(0)=0$. Let $p=(1,0)$, $q=(0,1)$, $r=(1,1)$. Consider the three numbers $f(p)$, $f(q)$, and $f(r)$. If one of them is zero then $f$ is not injective. Otherwise, either (i) at least two of them are strictly positive or (ii) at least two of them are strictly negative.

Assume wlog that $f(p)>0$ and $f(q)>0$. If $f(p)=f(q)$ then $f$ is not injective. If not, wlog $0<f(p)<f(q)$. Now the intermediate value theorem shows that there exists $x\in[0,q]$ with $f(x)=f(p)$. Hence $f$ is not injective.

EDIT: So now the OP asks about measurable functions. As measure spaces the euclidean spaces are all the same. There are ways to see this that are perhaps simpler than the following, but the following is more fun:

Let $p:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ be that Peano curve. In particular it's a continuous surjection. Of course there are various constructions of such a $p$; the one I have in mind satisfies $$p([0,1/4])=[0,1/2]^2.$$And in fact for any $j$ and $N$ there exist $m$ and $n$ such that $$p\left(\left[j4^{-N},(j+1)4^{-N}\right]\right)=[m2^{-N},(m+1)2^{-N}]\times [n2^{-N},(n+1)2^{-N}].$$This says that $p$ is measure-preserving.

Of course $p$ is not injective; it can't be because the interval and the square are not homeomorphic. But $p$ is injective off a certain null set; modifying $p$ in irrelevant ways on that null set gives a measure-preserving bijection between the unit interval and the unit square.

Better yet, modify $p$ on a null set to give a measure-preserving bijection from $[0,1)$ onto $[0,1)^2$. These half-open things tile the line and the plane nicely, giving a measure-preserving bijection from $\Bbb R$ onto $\Bbb R^2$.

---

One could construct maps from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^n$ similarly, and then compose to get maps from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$. Or note this: If $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ then $x\mapsto f(f(x_1,x_2),x_3)$ mape $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R$...

Comment: Ah right thank you!! What about when relaxing to measurables?

Comment: Measurable is no problem; as measure spaces there's no difference between $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Really??? I mean really?? Nice. Man that is great!!!! Can you explain how that is proven?

Comment: Soon, if nobody beats me to it...

Comment: Just not to make a stupid hasty mistake: That is one then also finds such maps between R4 and R2??  Like e.g. $\eta(x_\pm;y_\pm):=(\eta_x(x_\pm);\eta_y(y_\pm))$ and $\vartheta(x;y):=(\vartheta_x(x);\vartheta_y(y))$?

Comment: Do realize what overwhelming hypothesis you *(might)* have proven just right now???? :DDD

Comment: Did $\Bbb R^n$ in another edit. No, what overwhelming hypothesis may I have proved?

Comment: Regard finitely many mutually commuting unbounded normal operators. It is well-known that one can find *one* (product) spectral measure that reproduces *all* of them. But can you also find *one* unbounded normal operator that reproduces *all* of them? Guess! :D

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you mean by saying one operator "reproduces" another.

Comment: I mean that it is contained in the Borel functional calculus...

Comment: Moreover that endows the unbounded normal operators with a *directed* partial order. So one obtains a notion of limits. Moreover one can ask about Zorn' s lemma wether there are maximal unbounded normal operators. Man that is so great!!! :D

Comment: I am stunned! :D *(See the superalgebra thread!)*

Comment: Ok, seems to me the answer is yes and that I more or less proved it. This can't be a big deal - if correct this can't be anything new, since everything I wrote in that post is hugely classical...

Comment: Yes you proved it!!! :DDD Something soo *classical* has so *big* impact.

Comment: You're saying I've actually proved something new and interesting here? That's simply not possible...

Comment: Yes and nobody noticed!!! :DDD  Look into the big textbooks like Birman&Solomyak, Conway and so on...

Comment: Can you confirm the result holds for R4 and R2, please?

Comment: Ok, answer me this: Are the amazing things you say I've proved already well known for _bounded_ operators?

Comment: Yes, it holds for $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^4$. It's very well known.

Comment: As far as I know, no, it is simply not studied yet. There are results on the relations between similarity and unitarity. But that result is simply taken only until that far that one can find a joint spectral measure but not further.

Comment: There are results related to Fugledge-Putnam-Rosenblum that become a one-liner!! :DD *(See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/368576/79762).)*

Comment: I want to reward this to honour you. Is that ok?

Comment: Same time I'd like to accept zhw.'s answer instead so I can thank him too. *(Ok?)*

Comment: All that's fine. I really don't believe that all those smart people are unaware of the simple things I said here. You should find some expert and ask him why the amazing results don't follow...

Comment: Yes it seems impossible to me too. That is so simple that it *must* already be well-known.

Comment: It is eligle for bounty only in 2 days. Hope that's fine for you?

Comment: Fine. Don't worry about it...