# Prove that if $AA^T=A^TA$ and $AB=BA$ then $AB^T=B^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Prove that if $AA^T=A^TA$ and $AB=BA$ then $AB^T=B^TA$ where $A$ and $B$ are matrices.

It doesn't say of what order they are. Can somebody help me with this exam problem?

I know I should put my work here but I really don't know what to do. I would really like some help.

Comment: What information do you get from $AA^T=A^TA$? Search for matrices that commute with their transpose. They have certain properties.

Comment: Maybe consider $(XY)^T=Y^TX^T$ if I am not mistaken, $AB^T=(BA^T)^T=$..

Comment: @RubenKruepper does it have anything to do with the trace

Comment: Are the matrices complex?

Comment: It doesn't say anything

Comment: Presumably $A$ is real and $B$ is complex. The result is known as [Fuglede's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem) and [a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/368634) can be found in an earlier thread.

Answer (score 0):

Remarks:

1) $AB  = B A \Rightarrow B^T A^T = A^T B^T$;

2) $A B^T  = B^T A \iff B A^T  = A^T B \iff B A^T (AB)  = A^T B (AB) $,

Comment: For the last $\iff$ you seem to be assuming $AB$ is invertible.